# Solving a first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation (for a physics problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, physics

The following DE describes a physical problem involving electronic circuits. How can I solve it?

$$x(t)\cdot a+x'(t)\cdot b+c\cdot\ln\left(1+d\cdot x(t)\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x(t)=\dots$$

All the variables are real and positive and $x(0)=x_0$

I've no idea where to start what so ever. Thanks for any help or ideas

Comment: It is seperable. Having said that, it looks quite hard to integrate the resulting equation...$$t=-\int\frac{b\,dx}{c\ln(1+dx)+ax}$$Are you sure this should be integrable? Are you given any more information?

Comment: The final result must look like a downgoing exponential function, that is the thing I expect.

Comment: @JohnDoe: You notice that in your integral above, you've used "dx" in two utterly different ways. That seems OK to me, but it might confuse a beginner...

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes it does confuse me :(

Comment: Ah yes, that is true. I suppose thats the issue with using $d$ as a constant! We can let $d=D$, giving $$t=-\int\frac{b\,dx}{c\ln(1+Dx)+ax}$$ if that helps.

Comment: it seems to me,this integral may not have any closed form

Comment: Notice first that for $x>0$ the direction field is pointing downward toward zero. Then close to zero apply the approximation, using $\ln(1+d\,x)\approx d\,x$ is even simpler to solve than in the answer the Bernoulli equation that results from the quadratic approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note that this solution is only valid for $|Dx_0|<1$. The integral cannot be evaluated in closed form generally, but it can be approximated using a Taylor series.**

Given $$t=-\int\frac{b\,dx}{c\ln(1+Dx)+ax}$$one can expand the logarithm as a Taylor series, and ignore all terms excluding the lowest two order terms $Dx-\frac{D^2x^2}2$. $$\begin{align}t-t_0&=-\int^x\frac{b\,du}{(a+cD)u-\frac{cD^2}2u^2}=\frac2{cD^2}\int^x\frac{b\,du}{u^2-\frac{2(a+cD)}{cD^2}u}\end{align}$$Let $A=\frac{(a+cD)}{cD^2}$.
$$\begin{align}t-t_0&=\frac2{cD^2}\int^x\frac{b\,du}{(u-2A)u}\\&=-\frac{2b}{cD^2}\frac1{2A}\int^xdu\left(\frac{1}u-\frac{1}{u-2A}\right)\\&=\frac{b}{cAD^2}\ln \left(\frac{x-2A}{x}\right)\end{align}$$
Then inverting, $$x-2A=x\exp\left(\frac{cAD^2}b(t-t_0)\right)\\x=\frac{2A}{1-\exp\left(\frac{cAD^2}b(t-t_0)\right)}$$
Finally, applying the initial condition, $$x=\frac{x_0}{\exp\left(\frac{cAD^2}bt\right)+\frac{x_0}{2A}\left(1-\exp\left(\frac{cAD^2}bt\right)\right)}$$

We initially assumed $x_0$ was small, and we can see that with this assumption, the corresponding solution ensures that $x$ stays small as time passes. So for small $x_0$, this is a good approximation to the true solution.

Comment: You either meant to write $|Dx_0|<1$ or $|x_0|\ll 1$. As it is, the usefulness of your first condition strongly depends on the size of $D$. // One could present an easier calculation for this quadratic approximation of the logarithm by solving $0=ax+bx'+c(d\,x-\frac12 d^2\,x^2)$ as a Bernoulli equation; setting $u=x^{-1}$, finding $0=au-bu'+c(d\,u-\frac12d^2)$ which now is linear, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Going by @LutzL's suggestion we can linearize the equation for small $x$

$$ bx' + (a+cd)x = 0 $$

since $\ln(1+dx) \approx dx$

Then an approximation given by

$$ x(t) = x_0\exp\left(-\frac{(a+cd)}{b}t\right) $$

which resembles a decaying exponential as you've mentioned. Note that this approximation is only accurate if $|dx_0| \ll 1$ and is only valid for $t \ge 0$